# Magento 2.1.7 CE master-slave architecture

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, magento2

Is it possible to have single master and multiple slave architecture in magento2 CE?

The magento document - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_masterdb.html is applicable for Magento2 EE.

I am ok if I don't have multi master. I wanted single master and multiple slave architecture for Magento 2.1.7

Thank in advance.

Comment: Does Magento care if you configure Replication under the covers?

Comment: @RickJames could You please explain what particularly do You mean by saying that?